# How to get the required data types of function arguments in R Language?

Tags: r, docstring

How do I get the data types of arguments of a function? Let me explain you with an example of the `cor` function.

`args(cor)` will display the argument list:

```
function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", kendall", "spearman"))
```

How can I obtain get the data type required of `x` and `y` (e.g. `char`, `integer`, `list` et c)  before using it.

and i need to save the data types as well.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
?cor
```

to get help on `cor` function and read **Arguments** section. `?` works for every single function in R.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, Thanks for the help . But i need to save the argument data types . help(library) or ? library will display the results on console.unfortunately i am not able to save the argument data types . i need to save the types as well . That is the target i need to achieve.

Comment: OK, you did not mention this in your question ;)